# Error with Var express

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am trying to make an app at IBM bluemix which has three services: conversation, speech to text and text to speech. I want to a voice as well as text conversation with Watson. But i am getting error whenever I use 'require'. Eg in the below lines:

```
var express    = require('express'),
```

> "'require' is undefined.Add to eslint-env directive".

Please suggest what changes do I need to do to run my app?

Comment: What language, etc you using? eg. Flask, NodeJS, etc.

Comment: I am using Node.js.

Comment: Are you sure the code is run in node instead of some other environment, browser for example? Please put this in a script, run and paste here the results: `console.log(typeof window, typeof module);`. For browser, `module` will be undefined, for node `window` will be undefined.